# How to use Structr with ReactJS via RESTful APIs?

Tags: reactjs, structr

How to use [Structr](https://structr.com) with a frontend framework like ReactJS, Vue etc?

I want to create a React app entirely separately from Structr  that only talks to it via RESTful API.

How to talk to Structr via separate frontend via RESTful API?

Do I just create pages and render raw data which'll serve as paths for API endpoints?

Or does it have a "hidden" (can't seem to find it in the docs) RESTful API already present that I can use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Structr has a RESTful API - you can find the docs here: https://docs.structr.com/docs/rest-guide